# Excel Range Search and Sum

Tags: excel

Please excuse my rustiness with Excel, I switched careers and haven't had to use it for several years.

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet that will log individual donations, which is easy enough, where it becomes more problematic is that I wish to have a report tab/sheet that gives me totals by year and by month. I can't seem to pull the monthly totals together.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is search column B for the month and then sum the matching corresponding cell in H column. VLookUp only gives me the last record, I don't knwo what else to try.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider using a PivotTable.(`Insert -->PivotTable) They are scary at first, but extremely powerful for this type of task, and not actually that hard to use/create.

Comment: Thanks, I had considered that, but I'm going to be turning this file over to someone else to manage, and I want it to require essentially no knowledge of Excel whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See screenshot below for formula.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks, I can't believe I forgot about the SUMIF function. It's going to take me a while to get back into this.